# Can you explain the relationship between spin operator $S_z$ and rotation of a vector field (or wave function)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wavefunction, quantum-spin

I was studying *Rotational Invariance* in Quantum Mechanics from R. Shankar's book. Where I found on problem *12.5.1* that if $\vec{\Psi}(x,y)$ is a vector as such $\vec{\Psi}(x,y)=\psi_x(x,y)\hat{x}+\psi_y(x,y)\hat{y}$ then under infinetesimal roatation($\epsilon\hat{k}$) it changes as

$$\\ \psi_x \rightarrow \psi'_x = \psi_x(x+y\epsilon,y-x\epsilon) - \psi_y(x+y\epsilon,y-s\epsilon)\epsilon \\ \psi_y \rightarrow \psi'_y = \psi_x(x+y\epsilon,y-x\epsilon)\epsilon + \psi_y(x+y\epsilon,y-s\epsilon)\\$$

1. My first question is how to show this explicitly?

Another thing is the result:

$$\begin{bmatrix} \psi'_x\\ \psi'_y\end{bmatrix} =(\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix} -\frac{i\epsilon}{\hbar}\begin{bmatrix}L_z&0\\0&L_z\end{bmatrix}-\frac{i\epsilon}{\hbar}\begin{bmatrix}0&-i\hbar\\i\hbar&0\end{bmatrix}) $$

Which then written as $J_z=L_z^{(1)}\otimes I^{(2)} + I^{(1)}\otimes S_z^{(2)}$.

2. I didn't understand that part, why isn't $S_z$ diagonal here?

Clearly I am missing some basic points here so I would expect a detailed explanation from you.

n.b: This is not for my homework. I found plenty of solutions to the problems in this book. I just don't understand this one.

Comment: What do you mean why  $S_z$ is not diagonal? Why should it be? You see that the external rotation rotates the x and y components into each other, just as your formulas specify.

Answer (score 0):

When we rotate a vector field through an angle $\theta$, we obtain

$$\psi' = R(\psi(R^{-1}(x, y)))$$

That is, to get the field value after the rotation, you have to look at the field value at the point $R^{-1}(x, y)$ before the rotation, because that's the point that will get rotated into $(x, y)$ by the rotation; but then you also have to take that field value itself and rotate it, because the rotation affects not only the position of the field but also the direction.

(This is illustrated by Figure 12.1, which is referred to by Exercise 12.5.1.)

Note that in general, depending on the type of the field, the outside $R$ operator may be different from the inside one. For example, for a scalar field, it will be trivial (there is no field direction to be acted upon by the rotation) and for a spinor or tensor field, it will be different from the one for a vector field. The inside $R$ operator will always be the one applicable to vectors, since the position vector is a vector.

To determine what happens under an infinitesimal rotation, we just need to know the infinitesimal form of the $R$ operator. We can write it as $R = I + J\,\mathrm{d}\theta$, dropping higher order terms in $\mathrm{d}\theta$. In other words, we only care about the first derivative of $R$ with respect to $\theta$ (which is $J$). This is because we only care about the first order of the $\psi'$ dependence on $\theta$, and by the chain rule, derivatives of $R$ of order higher than the first can't affect the first derivative of $\psi'$.

Since

$$ R(\theta) = \begin{pmatrix} \cos \theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos \theta \end{pmatrix} $$

It follows that

$$ R(0 + \mathrm{d}\theta) \approx I + \mathrm{d}\theta \begin{pmatrix} -\sin 0 & -\cos 0 \\ \cos 0 & -\sin 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -\mathrm{d}\theta \\ \mathrm{d}\theta & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

Note that the inverse operation is just $R(-\mathrm{d}\theta)$. Finally

$$ \psi' \approx \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -\mathrm{d}\theta \\ \mathrm{d}\theta & 1 \end{pmatrix} \psi \left[\begin{pmatrix} 1 & \mathrm{d}\theta \\ -\mathrm{d}\theta & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}\right] $$

If you use $\epsilon_z$ to denote $\mathrm{d}\theta$ and write out this expression in components then you get the form shown in the question.

As for your second question, you might be confusing this $S_z$ with the one for spinors, $S_z = \frac{\hbar}{2}\sigma_z$ (with $\sigma$ denoting the Pauli matrices). *That* $S_z$ is diagonal because when writing down spinors, we choose to use a basis consisting of eigenstates of $S_z$. *This* $S_z$ is the one for two-dimensional vectors, not spinors, so it's a different matrix, and in particular you shouldn't expect it to be diagonal because the coordinate basis vectors aren't eigenvectors of rotations around the z-axis (how could they be?)